# Identify the installed Oracle driver, Scan the .NET GAC for Incompatible Assemblies

Tags: rust, oracle

My day job is supporting a piece of software that just started using the DevArt Oracle drivers, which utilize the `Oracle.DataAccess` .NET drivers.

However, the assemblies in the .NET GAC may not uninstall correctly, and I have encountered later assemblies that do not match the installed Oracle client, and which therefore do not function.

The painful resolution is to send the user a copy of gacutil.exe and have them export a listing of the GAC to identify driver mismatches.

This Rust code automates identifying Oracle assembly mismatches in the GAC.

```
extern crate regex;
extern crate xml;

use std::fs;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io::{Error, ErrorKind};
use regex::Regex;
use xml::{Event, Parser};
use std::path::Path;

/// Traverses the Inventory and ContentsXML subfolders and returns
/// the contents of the inventory.xml file.
///
/// # Example
/// let inventory = read_ora_inventory("c:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\");
fn read_ora_inventory( inventory_loc: &str ) -> io::Result<String> {

    // given the Oracle folder under Program Files get the filename
    let mut file_path = String::from(inventory_loc);
    file_path.push_str(".\\Inventory\\ContentsXML\\inventory.xml");

    // slurp xml file and return
    let mut f = try!(File::open(file_path));
    let mut s = String::new();
    match f.read_to_string(&mut s) {
        Ok(_) => Ok(s),
        Err(e) => Err(e),
    }
}

/// Parses out the SAVED_WITH tag from the Oracle inventory
fn parse_version( inventory: &str ) -> io::Result<String> {

    // Create a new Parser and feed the inventory in
    let mut p = Parser::new();

    // Feed data to be parsed
    p.feed_str(&inventory);

    // Scan file looking for "SAVED_WITH" tag
    let mut found = false;
    let mut version = String::new();
    for event in p {
        match event.unwrap() {
            Event::ElementStart(tag) => { 
                if tag.name.as_str()=="SAVED_WITH" {
                    found = true; 
                }},
            Event::Characters(verstr) => { 
                if found { 
                    version.push_str(&verstr);
                    found = false;
                }},
            _ => ()
        }
    }
    match version.is_empty() {
        true => Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "Oracle version not found in inventory.")),
        _ => Ok(version),
    }
}

/// Reformats Oracle version to match .NET Oracle driver version string
fn get_net_match_ver( version: &str ) -> io::Result<String> {

    // split installed version into components
    let mut expected = String::new();
    let split = Regex::new(r"(\d+).(\d+).(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)").unwrap();
    for cmp in split.captures_iter(&*version) {
        expected.push_str("2.");
        expected.push_str(cmp.at(1).unwrap());
        expected.push_str(cmp.at(2).unwrap());
        expected.push_str(".");
        expected.push_str(if cmp.at(3).unwrap()=="0" { "" } else { cmp.at(3).unwrap() });
        expected.push_str(if cmp.at(4).unwrap()=="0" { "" } else { cmp.at(4).unwrap() });
        expected.push_str(".");
        expected.push_str(cmp.at(5).unwrap());
    }

    match expected.is_empty() {
        true => Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "Unable to parse Oracle version.")),
        _ => Ok(expected),
    }
}

/// Checks if a path refers to a later version
/// ...
/// Example
///
/// Oracle.DataAccess/2.112.1.0__89b483f429c47342/oracle.dataaccess.dll
/// Here we check the second component shown, treating it as a filename.
fn check_ver( verpath: &Path, expected: &str ) -> bool {

    // get final component -- better way to this?
    let name = verpath.file_name().unwrap().to_str();
    let version = name.unwrap().split("__").next().unwrap();

    // return true if we are ok.
    // if version > expected, we'll need to remove it
    version<=expected
}

/// Makes an assembly name that we can pass to gacutil /u
///
/// # Example
///
/// Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=AMD64
fn make_assembly_name( gac_type: &str, verpath: &Path ) -> io::Result<String> {

    // get main assembly name
    let name = verpath.parent().unwrap().file_name().unwrap();

    // get version and key
    let ver_key = verpath.file_name().unwrap().to_str();
    let v: Vec<&str> = ver_key.unwrap().split("__").collect();
    let ver = v.get(0).unwrap();
    let key = v.get(1).unwrap();

    // build assembly name
    let mut assembly = String::new();
    assembly.push_str(name.to_str().unwrap());
    assembly.push_str(", Version=");
    assembly.push_str(ver);
    assembly.push_str(", Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=");
    assembly.push_str(key);
    assembly.push_str(", processorArchitecture=");
    assembly.push_str(match gac_type { "GAC_64" => "AMD64", "GAC_32" => "x86", "GAC_MSIL" => "MSIL", _ => "##Unknown Arch##",});

    Ok(assembly)
}

/// Scans gac looking for Oracle assemblies that are greater than the passed version
fn scan_gac( gac: &str, expected: &str ) -> io::Result<Vec<String>> {

    // let gac folder name
    let p = Path::new(gac);
    let gac_folder = p.file_name().unwrap().to_str().unwrap();

    // create empty Vec<String> to return list of bad assemblies
    let mut vec: Vec<String> = Vec::new();

    // regexp to find Oracle
    let oracle = Regex::new(r"^.*Oracle.*$").unwrap();

    // iterate over paths
    let paths = fs::read_dir(gac).unwrap();
    for path in paths {
        let dirpath = path.unwrap().path();
        let dirstr = dirpath.to_str().unwrap();

        // Oracle?
        if oracle.is_match(dirstr) {

            let verpath = fs::read_dir(dirstr).unwrap();
            for ver in verpath {
                let verpath = ver.unwrap().path();
                if !check_ver( &verpath, expected ) {
                    vec.push(make_assembly_name(&gac_folder,&verpath).unwrap())
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Ok(vec)
}


fn main() {

    // open Oracle inventory
    let inventory32 = match read_ora_inventory("c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Oracle\\") {
        Ok(data) => data,
        _ => "".to_string(),
    };
    let inventory64 = match read_ora_inventory("c:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\") {
        Ok(data) => data,
        _ => "".to_string(),
    };

    // parse version out of XML
    let version32 = match !inventory32.is_empty() { 
        true => parse_version(&*inventory32).unwrap(),
        _ => "".to_string(),
    };
    let version64 = match !inventory64.is_empty() { 
        true => parse_version(&*inventory64).unwrap(),
        _ => "".to_string(),
    };

    // check drivers match
    if version32.is_empty() && version64.is_empty() { panic!("No Oracle install found."); };
    if !version32.is_empty() && !version64.is_empty() && version32!=version64 {
        println!("Version {} (32-bit) and version {} (64-bit) found.",version32,version64);
        panic!("Different Oracle versions installed.");
    };

    // get single expected version
    let ora_version = if version32.is_empty() { version64 } else { version32 };

    // get version to match .NET Oracle driver
    let expected = get_net_match_ver(&*ora_version).unwrap();
    println!("Expected .NET version is: {}",expected);
    println!("");

    // scan gac for later versions
    let kill_assembly_list32 = scan_gac("c:/windows/assembly/GAC_32/",&*expected).unwrap();
    for assembly in kill_assembly_list32 {
        println!("gacutil /u \"{}\"",assembly);
    }
    let kill_assembly_list64 = scan_gac("c:/windows/assembly/GAC_64/",&*expected).unwrap();
    for assembly in kill_assembly_list64 {
        println!("gacutil /u \"{}\"",assembly);
    }
}
```

The following output is given for incompatible driver assemblies:

```
Expected .NET version is: 2.112.1.0
gacutil /u "Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.221.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=AMD64"
gacutil /u "Oracle.Database.Extensions, Version=2.221.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=AMD64"
```

This output could be piped to the shell to fix up the GAC.

Obviously there are probably many better ways to implement this code in idiomatic Rust. I'm looking forward to hopefully seeing a big reduction in code size also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Learn to love [rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustfmt). Specifically, there are no spaces in function argument lists.
2. Can use `self` in `use` statements, there's no need to specify a separate line.
3. Overall, error handling could b improved. Prefer `expect` over `unwrap` and prefer returning the error with `Result` instead of panicking. Some functions say they return `Result` but never have an actual error! Also, I used the `?` operator because it's new.
4. Check out the `format!` macro; very useful for constructing strings all at once.
5. Use `Result::map` to convert the success type. There's also `Option::map`.
6. There's a redundant `&` when calling `feed_str`.
7. Consider using DOM-based XML parsing if your input XML isn't that large.
8. In many cases, `&*` is unneeded. Can get `&str` from `&String`, no need to dereference.
9. I don't imagine that you really want an iterator of regex matches, only just the first? Then use `captures`. This allows mapping the `Option`, and converting it to a `Result`.
10. I'd split up the capture stuff into separate lines.
11. I don't like `cmp` as the capture variable name, it reads like "compare" which doesn't make sense there.
12. `foo.get(...).unwrap()` should just be `foo[...]`
13. There's no need to specify item type when collecting; `Vec<_>` is fine.
14. Instead of collecting to a vector, just take the first two things off the iterator. No allocation.
15. Consider creating an enum for the various types of GAC. Then you don't have to have `"GAC_64" => "AMD64"` inline in your code.
16. Don't use a regex where a simple substring comparison will do ("Oracle")
17. Make use of `Option` and `Result`; don't use default values (like empty strings) to mean failure.
18. Use raw strings for Windows-style paths (r"C:\Program Files"). Note that forwards slashes are fine too.
19. Combine iterators with `chain`, avoiding the duplication in formatting and printing.
20. There are a lot of beginner-level comments, which is surprising given the good quality of the rest of the code. "return true if we are ok" is a prime example of a comment that doesn't add any value to the rest of the code. Introduce new types or functions to provide names.
21. In documentation comments, surround code examples in a code fence (```` ``` ````) to have them be compiled and/or executed. This ensures that the example is valid.

```
extern crate regex;
extern crate xml;

use std::fs::{self, File};
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::path::Path;

use std::error::Error;

use regex::Regex;
use xml::{Event, Parser};

/// Traverses the Inventory and ContentsXML subfolders and returns
/// the contents of the inventory.xml file.
///
/// # Example
/// let inventory = read_ora_inventory(r"c:\Program Files\Oracle\");
fn read_ora_inventory(inventory_loc: &str) -> Result<String, Box<Error>> {
    let file_path = format!(r"{}.\Inventory\ContentsXML\inventory.xml", inventory_loc);

    let mut f = try!(File::open(file_path));
    let mut s = String::new();
    f.read_to_string(&mut s).map(|_| s).map_err(Into::into)
}

/// Parses out the SAVED_WITH tag from the Oracle inventory
fn parse_version(inventory: &str) -> Result<String, Box<Error>> {
    let mut p = Parser::new();
    p.feed_str(inventory);

    // Scan file looking for "SAVED_WITH" tag
    let mut found = false;
    let mut version = String::new();
    for event in p {
        match event.unwrap() {
            Event::ElementStart(tag) => {
                if tag.name.as_str() == "SAVED_WITH" {
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            Event::Characters(verstr) => {
                if found {
                    version.push_str(&verstr);
                    found = false;
                }
            }
            _ => (),
        }
    }
    match version.is_empty() {
        true => Err("Oracle version not found in inventory.")?,
        _ => Ok(version),
    }
}

/// Reformats Oracle version to match .NET Oracle driver version string
fn get_net_match_ver(version: &str) -> Result<String, Box<Error>> {

    // split installed version into components
    let split = Regex::new(r"(\d+).(\d+).(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)").unwrap();

    split.captures(version).map(|cap| {
        let cap1 = cap.at(1).unwrap();
        let cap2 = cap.at(2).unwrap();
        let cap3 = cap.at(3).unwrap();
        let cap4 = cap.at(4).unwrap();
        let cap5 = cap.at(5).unwrap();

        let cap3 = if cap3 == "0" { "" } else { cap3 };
        let cap4 = if cap4 == "0" { "" } else { cap4 };

        format!("2.{}{}.{}{}.{}", cap1, cap2, cap3, cap4, cap5)
    }).ok_or("Unable to parse Oracle version.".into())
}

/// Checks if a path refers to a later version
/// ...
/// Example
///
/// Oracle.DataAccess/2.112.1.0__89b483f429c47342/oracle.dataaccess.dll
/// Here we check the second component shown, treating it as a filename.
fn check_ver(verpath: &Path, expected: &str) -> bool {

    // get final component -- better way to this?
    let name = verpath.file_name().unwrap().to_str();
    let version = name.unwrap().split("__").next().unwrap();

    // return true if we are ok.
    // if version > expected, we'll need to remove it
    version <= expected
}

/// Makes an assembly name that we can pass to gacutil /u
///
/// # Example
///
/// Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=AMD64
fn make_assembly_name(gac_type: &str, verpath: &Path) -> Result<String, Box<Error>> {

    // get main assembly name
    let name = verpath.parent().ok_or("No parent directory")?;
    let name = name.file_name().ok_or("parent directory has no file name")?;
    let name = name.to_str().ok_or("parent directory is not Unicode")?;

    // get version and key
    let ver_key = verpath.file_name().ok_or("version path has no filename")?;
    let ver_key = ver_key.to_str().ok_or("version path is not Unicode")?;

    let mut ver_key_parts = ver_key.split("__");
    let ver = ver_key_parts.next().ok_or("missing first version component")?;
    let key = ver_key_parts.next().ok_or("missing second version component")?;

    // build assembly name
    let gac_type = match gac_type {
        "GAC_64" => "AMD64",
        "GAC_32" => "x86",
        "GAC_MSIL" => "MSIL",
        _ => "##Unknown Arch##",
    };

    Ok(format!(
        "{}, Version={}, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken={}, processorArchitecture={}",
        name, ver, key, gac_type
    ))
}


/// Scans gac looking for Oracle assemblies that are greater than the passed version
fn scan_gac(gac: &str, expected: &str) -> Result<Vec<String>, Box<Error>> {
    let p = Path::new(gac);
    let gac_folder = p.file_name().ok_or("gac folder doesn't have file name")?;
    let gac_folder = gac_folder.to_str().ok_or("gac folder isn't Unicode")?;

    // create empty Vec<String> to return list of bad assemblies
    let mut vec: Vec<_> = Vec::new();

    for path in fs::read_dir(gac)? {
        let dirpath = path?.path();

        let dirstr = dirpath.to_str().ok_or("directory isn't Unicode")?;

        // Oracle?
        if dirstr.contains("Oracle") {
            let verpath = fs::read_dir(dirstr)?;
            for ver in verpath {
                let verpath = ver?.path();
                if !check_ver(&verpath, expected) {
                    vec.push(make_assembly_name(&gac_folder, &verpath)?)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Ok(vec)
}


fn main() {
    // open Oracle inventory
    let inventory32 = read_ora_inventory(r"c:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\");
    let inventory64 = read_ora_inventory(r"c:\Program Files\Oracle\");

    // parse version out of XML
    let version32 = inventory32.and_then(|i| parse_version(&i));
    let version64 = inventory64.and_then(|i| parse_version(&i));

    match (version32.as_ref(), version64.as_ref()) {
        (Err(_), Err(_)) => panic!("No Oracle install found."),
        (Ok(version32), Ok(version64)) if version32 != version64 => {
            panic!("Different Oracle versions installed. \
                    Version {} (32-bit) and version {} (64-bit) found.",
                   version32,
                   version64);
        },
        _ => ()
    }

    let ora_version = version32.or(version64).unwrap();

    // get version to match .NET Oracle driver
    let expected = get_net_match_ver(&ora_version).unwrap();
    println!("Expected .NET version is: {}", expected);
    println!("");

    // scan gac for later versions
    let kill_assembly_list32 = scan_gac("c:/windows/assembly/GAC_32/", &expected).unwrap();
    let kill_assembly_list64 = scan_gac("c:/windows/assembly/GAC_64/", &expected).unwrap();

    for assembly in kill_assembly_list32.iter().chain(&kill_assembly_list64) {
        println!("gacutil /u \"{}\"", assembly);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh this is great stuff. I've been bogged down trying to fit some of this into iterators, but improving what is there is probably a better approach. Lots of reading to do for me.
Many thanks!

Comment: @JonathanWatmough I actually asked the creator of [Itertools](https://github.com/bluss/rust-itertools) to give a second opinion of the `for` loop starting at `fs::read_dir(gac)` to write it with more iterators. They said: *I don't think I would want to write it with iterator adaptors. `?` is Rust's best error handling style and iterator adaptors don't mix well with it*

Comment: I've pushed this to a repository on GitHub. See [diff on GitHub](https://github.com/watmough/check_ora/commit/c434aebc55a3a8c47ebf7bfb650beda916af50c9) for the changes.